# Stream to youtube live using skylink.io API

Tags: webrtc, youtube-livestreaming-api, skylink

Is it possible that video and audio stream produced by skylink.io APIs be streamed directly to youtube Live ?

In other words, do they provide rtmp links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skylink does not provide RTMP streaming of your streams as per their official SDKs.

One of my partners also wanted to have that feature to stream to youtube in their product, so they contacted Skylink and manually got it set up for his account.

It comes with a price tag though !

Comment: Let me have a look into it

Comment: Thanks ! i checked with them .. and Skylink is willing to help me

Comment: They did not help me for it though. Seems they don't want this feature open to all

Comment: Yeah seems so. Otherwise they would have surely advertised it publically.

Comment: Full Disclosure: I'm the Director,Engineering at Temasys. 

Firstly, we do not directly support RTMP streams. We also have also not implemented this on the behalf of any customer.

We certainly do have those who do this and we have supported them in THEIR initiatives, however, only specifically where they interface with Temasys components. 
Temasys has not and has no plans to offer custom developed solutions for this. In some cases, where there is a technical fit, we can refer our customers to third-party developers to implement this or offer consultation services on their behalf.